# Nested for loops - getting the right order

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, indentation

I'm having trouble grasping how to get right the right order of output, when doing nested for loops.

I have a list of integers:

```
[7, 9, 12]
```

And a .txt with lines of DNA sequence data.

```
>Ind1 AACTCAGCTCACG
>Ind2 GTCATCGCTACGA 
>Ind3 CTTCAAACTGACT
```

I am trying to make a nested for loop, that takes the first integer (7), goes through the lines of text and prints the charachter at position 7 for each line. Then takes the next integer, and prints each character at position 9 for each line.

```
with (Input) as getletter:
    for line in getletter:
        if line [0] == ">":

            for pos in position:
                snp = line[pos]
                print line[pos], str(pos)
```

When I run the above code, I get the data I want, but in the wrong order, like so:

```
A  7
T  9
G  12
T  7
A  9
G  12
T  7
C  9
A  12
```

What I want is this:

```
A  7
T  7
T  7
T  9
A  9
C  9
G  12
G  12
A  12
```

I suspect the problem can be solved by changing the indentation of the code, but I cannot get it right.

------EDIT--------

I've tried to swap the two loops around, but I am obviously not getting the bigger picture of this gives me the same (wrong) result as above.

```
with (Input) as getsnps:
    for line in getsnps:
        if line[0] == ">":
            hit = line
        for pos in position:
                print hit[pos], pos
```

Comment: Your print statement will **not** produce the first output; it'll print `A 7`, `T 9`, etc, so the letter and position are swapped.

Comment: I removed the `python-3.x` tag; you are using Python 2 here, as evidenced by `print` being a statement.

Comment: How do you get from the list `[7, 9, 12]` to the positions `31` and `119`?

Comment: You can swap the loops, but that'd mean you had to re-read the file from start to end each time. How many lines are we talking about here?

Comment: An alternative would be to store the file content in an array using readlines() and working in memory. Swapping inner and outter loop after that will have the same cost.

Comment: If the file is small enough, it doesn't really matter which one you do. If it's big enough… then what you do depends on how much RAM you have (and whether you're on a 64-bit machine), how fast your drive is and/or how much disk cache you have, … But just do whichever one makes sense to you first, and then if it's too slow, at least you have something to optimized that's working and that you understand. :)

Comment: Sorry for the errors in the question, I have editet to fix them. @Martijn Pieters: A few hundred thousand lines of sequences and about 20.000 lines of positions with 1-4 positions in each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying an answer:

```
with (Input) as getletter:
    lines=[x.strip() for x in getLetter.readlines() if x.startswith('>') ]
    for pos in position:
        for line in lines:
            snp = line[pos]
            print ("%s\t%s" % (pos,snp))
```

The file is read and cached into an array (lines, discarding file not starting with `>`)
we then iterate over the position then the lines and print the expected result.

Please note that you should check that your offset is not bigger than your line.

Alternative without list comprehension (will use more memory, especially if you have a lot of useless lines (i.e. not starting with '>')

```
with (Input) as getletter:       
    lines=getLetter.readlines()
    for pos in position:
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('>'):
                 snp = line[pos]
                 print ("%s\t%s" % (pos,snp))
```

Alternative with another storage (assuming position is small and Input is big)

```
with (Input) as getletter:
    storage=dict()
    for p in positions:
        storage[p]=[]
    for line in getLetter:
        for p in positions:
            storage[p]+=[line[pos]]
for (k,v) in storage.iteritems():
    print ("%s -> %s" % (k, ",".join(v))
```

if positions contains a value bigger than size of line, using `line[p]` will trigger an exception (IndexError). You can either catch it or test for it

```
try:
    a=line[pos]
except IndexError:
    a='X'

if pos>len(line):
   a='X'
else:
   a=line[pos]
```

Comment: Assuming that `positions` is rather small, you could also just store the chars in those positions instead of all the lines.

Comment: @Bruce, could you show me how to do the same, but without the list comprehension (I think that is what it is), as I am not familiar with these yet (still very new to this)? Also, could you elaborate on the meaning of the offset being bigger than the line?

Comment: @hjalte : did the alternative (and the one proposed by @tobias_k)